# graph time and space complexity representations

Tags: graph, time-complexity, space-complexity

I wonder why graph algorithms time and space complexities are mostly represented using |E| and |V| instead of V and E. Every other algorithm's time and space complexities are represented using normal alphabets like
N or NlogN. Why the graph algorithms are represented in the mod(|E|) like way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In graph algorithms, both `E` and `V` are sets, not numbers. `E` is the set of edges and `V` is the set of vertices.

The complexity function is of numerical values. There is no meaning in `log(E)` or `E^2`, unless you refer to the *size* of the set. This is exactly what the absolute value does for sets, `|X|` means the size of the set `X`. This means, `|E|` and `|V|` respectively are the number of edges and vertices in the graph.

When you usually see `n`, it means the size of the input. In graphs, we split it to `|V|` and `|E|`.
A common notation for graphs is using `|V|=n` and `|E|=m`, and then you use `n,m`, like you are used to in other places.